# Mean value theorem for multivariate integral

Tags: real-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-theorem

While trying to prove the following statement:

> $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set, $p\in U$ and
> $F:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ a smooth vector field, Prove that
> $$\textrm{div}(F)(p)=\underset{r\to0}{\textrm{lim}}\frac{1}{\textrm{Vol}(B_{r}(p))}\intop_{\partial B_{r}(p)}\langle F,\hat{n}\rangle d\sigma$$

I was told that I could use some form of MVT for integrals of the form:
For $f$ a scalar function which is continuous on $B_{r}(p)$ There exists $q\in B_{r}(p)$ such that the following holds
$$f(c)=\frac{1}{\textrm{Vol}(B_{r}(p))}\intop_{B_{r}(p)}f(x) dx$$

I have been trying to find proof for this and couldn't, I tried proving it myself and am not too sure where to even start. Is this even correct?

**EDIT**
Assuming this is true, using Divergence theorem I'm able to prove the statement but the question remains.
$$\underset{r\to0}{\textrm{lim}}\frac{1}{\textrm{Vol}(B_{r}(p))}\intop_{\partial B_{r}(p)}\langle F,\hat{n}\rangle d\sigma = \underset{r\to0}{\textrm{lim}}\frac{1}{\textrm{Vol}(B_{r}(p))}\intop_{B_{r}(p)}\mathrm{div}\left(F\right)dx
 = \underset{r\to0}{\textrm{lim}}\frac{1}{\textrm{Vol}(B_{r}(p))}\intop_{B_{r}(p)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial F_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}\left(x\right)dx
 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\underset{r\to0}{\textrm{lim}}\frac{\intop_{B_{r}(p)}\frac{\partial F_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}\left(x\right)dx}{\textrm{Vol}(B_{r}(p))}
 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\underset{r\to0}{\textrm{lim}}\frac{\partial F_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}\left(c\left(i,r\right)\right)
 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial F_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}\left(\underset{r\to0}{\textrm{lim}}c\left(i,r\right)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial F_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}\left(p\right)=\textrm{div}(F)(p)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose not, i.e. there does not exist any $c\in B_r(p)$ such that $f(c)=f_{avg}$, where I denote $f_{avg}$ as the average integral of $f$ over $B_r(p)$.

We must have that either $f>f_{avg}$ or $f<f_{avg}$ on the whole of $B_r(p)$. This is due to assuming there are $x,y\in B_r(p)$ with $f(x)<f_{avg}<f(y)$, then restricting $f$ onto the line segment connecting $x,y$ contradicts intermediate value theorem.

Of course $f>f_{avg}$ or the reverse case are impossible.